# How to find the first logical unit in dword in ARM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to know how I can find the first logical unit(single bit) in a dword with registers R0 and R1, for example, from right to left. How can I achieve the described above?

I have tried iterating through the elements of a dword, but I do not seem to understand what's expected from me correctly. Also tried to shift right and left, with no luck overall.

```
MOV R2, R0, LSR #31
loop:
MOVS R0, R0, LSL #2
ADC R2, R2, R0, LSR #31
bne loop
```

I want to use the previously described for finding the current index of the single bit

Comment: What do you mean by finding _"the first logical unit"_? Are you talking about find the first bit that is set? If so, you could use the `clz` instruction on ARMv5T and later archiectures.

Comment: Oh, so by counting the leading zero I can get the index of the first `1` met in the dword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CLZ`to count the leading zeros. By subtracting the leading zeros from `31` you can the get the location of the first `1` in a byte.

```
CLZ R1, R0
RSB R1, R1, #31
```

`R0` contains the `DWORD` you want to work on.

`R1` at the end contains the "first logical unit".

> [The CLZ instruction counts the number of leading zeros in the value in Rm and returns the result in Rd. The result value is 32 if no bits are set in the source register, and zero if bit 31 is set.](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289868426.htm)

When the `S` optional suffix is added to `RSB` the [condition flags](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731160609.htm) will be updated and a `#0` register can be detected.

Comment: ARM has an `rsb` (reverse-subtract) instruction; you don't need a separate `mov r1, #8`.  But CLZ counts leading zeros in a 32-bit *word*, so you should be subtracting from 32 unless you're talking about the index within the high byte.  (Err actually it should be 31 - clz(x)` because you want a 0..31 for the bit index.)  Also your example doesn't need to mess around with static memory locations and clutter your example with that; comment it with input and output registers.

Comment: I'll go and update the answer. @PeterCordes. I must've overlooked the `rsb`